# How can I use psutil to Show Values which are Comparable to the Task Manager's Values?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, taskmanager, psutil

I need your help with a psutil script. I want to log memory and CPU usage of a python 2 script in percent. For that I use something similar to the following loop:

```
while True:
    for process in psutil.process_iter():
        with process.oneshot():
            if process.pid == os.getpid():
                metrics_file.write("CPU-%: {} | MEMORY: {}".format(
                    process.cpu_percent(1)/psutil.cpu_count(),
                    process.memory_percent()
                ))
```

My problem is that the values in the Task Manager are strongly different. CPU-% is consistently two to three times higher, memory-% up to ten times. It appears that I have made an arithmetical mistake, but I cannot see where.

Thank you for your help.

Note: In the task manager, I've checked for the correct PID and switched to percentage values.

Edit: Since I had no success with psutil, I used Windows' performance monitoring tool to log the cpu values as csv files and process them from there on. A guide can be found [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/perf_collect_perfmon.htm). Also, if you want to access the PID with this tool, you can find a way to do so in [this post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/perfmon-identifying-processes-by-pid-instead-of-instance/ba-p/374561).

All the best! Max

Comment: Not sure if this is the case, but "2-3 times higher" suggests something about multiple cores vs single core. That would not explain memory though.

Comment: Thanks dankal, I considered the amount of logical processors, but had no success. I found a different approach, though. I've edited my post above.

Comment: Can you provide actual steps to reproduce your numbers? That fragment from a script doesn't really help...